# Gatsbyjs + Wordpress GraphQL error `Cannot query field`

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

I am trying to set up a Gatsby site backed by a Wordpress CMS. I am following along the instructions here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md.

When I try to run `gatsby develop` on the provided template, I get a slew of GraphQL errors about fields/nodes not existing. A few highlights:

```
Field "databaseId" is not defined by type WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdgeFilterInput.
Cannot read property 'allWpPost' of undefined
Cannot query field "menuItemId" on type "WpMenuItem".
Cannot query field "connectedObject" on type "WpMenuItem".
Cannot query field "remoteFile" on type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "firstName" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "lastName" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "uri" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "description" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "avatar" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".
Cannot query field "remoteFile" on type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge".
```

The full log:

```
> gatsby develop

info gatsby-source-wordpress

This is either your first build or the cache was cleared.

Please wait while your WordPress data is synced to your Gatsby cache.


Maybe now's a good time to get up and stretch? :D


success gatsby-source-wordpress ingest WPGraphQL schema - 3.255s

success createSchemaCustomization - 10.324s

success gatsby-source-wordpress Category - 1.393s - fetched 1

success gatsby-source-wordpress Comment - 1.408s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress ContentType - 1.431s - fetched 3

success gatsby-source-wordpress MenuItem - 1.766s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress PostFormat - 2.869s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress Tag - 2.890s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress Menu - 2.921s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress Post - 3.062s - fetched 1

success gatsby-source-wordpress Page - 3.970s - fetched 2

success gatsby-source-wordpress UserRole - 4.136s - fetched 0

success gatsby-source-wordpress Taxonomy - 4.175s - fetched 3

success gatsby-source-wordpress User - 4.195s - fetched 1

success gatsby-source-wordpress MediaItem - 1.886s - fetched 1

success gatsby-source-wordpress creating nodes - 1.895s

success gatsby-source-wordpress fetching nodes - 6.128s - 12 total

success gatsby-source-wordpress fetch root fields - 1.102s

success Downloading remote files - 2.211s - 1/1 0.45/s

success source and transform nodes - 10.207s

success building schema - 0.999s

warn Warning: Empty string transition configs (e.g., `{ on: { '': ... }}`) for transient transitions

warn Warning: Empty string transition configs (e.g., `{ on: { '': ... }}`) for transient transitions

warn Warning: Empty string transition configs (e.g., `{ on: { '': ... }}`) for transient transitions


ERROR #85901 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Field "databaseId" is not defined by type WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdgeFilterInput.


File: gatsby-node.js:32:3



ERROR #11321 PLUGIN


"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:


Cannot read property 'allWpPost' of undefined


30 | await createBlog(props, { perPage, blogURI })

31 | await createCategories(props, { perPage })

> 32 | await createAuthors(props, { perPage })

| ^

33 | }

34 |

35 | const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)


File: gatsby-node.js:32:3




TypeError: Cannot read property 'allWpPost' of undefined


- createAuthors.js:37

/home/node/www/create/createAuthors.js:37:17


- task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections

internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5


- async Promise.all


- createAuthors.js:23 module.exports

/home/node/www/create/createAuthors.js:23:3


- gatsby-node.js:32 Object.exports.createPages

/home/node/www/gatsby-node.js:32:3


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:231 runAPI

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:231:22


- api-runner-node.js:339 Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:339:17


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:338

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:338:14


- timers.js:458 processImmediate

internal/timers.js:458:21


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:330

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:330:13


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:246 module.exports

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:246:3


- create-pages.ts:21 createPages

[www]/[gatsby]/src/services/create-pages.ts:21:9


- index.ts:48 bootstrap

[www]/[gatsby]/src/bootstrap/index.ts:48:9


- develop-process.ts:112 module.exports

[www]/[gatsby]/src/commands/develop-process.ts:112:53



failed createPages - 0.391s

warn Warning: Empty string transition configs (e.g., `{ on: { '': ... }}`) for transient transitions

warn Warning: Empty string transition configs (e.g., `{ on: { '': ... }}`) for transient transitions

success createPagesStatefully - 0.219s

success updating schema - 0.089s

success onPreExtractQueries - 0.003s


ERROR #85901 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Field "databaseId" is not defined by type WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdgeFilterInput.


File: src/templates/archive.js:51:19



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "menuItemId" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "menuItemId" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "menuItemId" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "menuItemId" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/MenuModal.js:17:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "connectedObject" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "connectedObject" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "connectedObject" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "connectedObject" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/MenuModal.js:18:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "menuItemId" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "menuItemId" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "menuItemId" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "menuItemId" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/Menu.js:14:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "connectedObject" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "connectedObject" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "connectedObject" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "connectedObject" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/Menu.js:15:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "menuItemId" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "menuItemId" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "menuItemId" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "menuItemId" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/SocialMenu.js:72:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "connectedObject" on type "WpMenuItem".


If you don't expect "connectedObject" to exist on the type "WpMenuItem" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "connectedObject" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "connectedObject" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpMenuItem":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/components/SocialMenu.js:73:13



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "remoteFile" on type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "remoteFile" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "remoteFile" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "remoteFile" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:132:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "name" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "name" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "name" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "name" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:137:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "firstName" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "firstName" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "firstName" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "firstName" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:138:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "lastName" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "lastName" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "lastName" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "lastName" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:139:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "uri" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "uri" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "uri" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "uri" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:140:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "description" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "description" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "description" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "description" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:141:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "avatar" on type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "avatar" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "avatar" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "avatar" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithAuthorToUserConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/post.js:142:7



ERROR #85923 GRAPHQL


There was an error in your GraphQL query:


Cannot query field "remoteFile" on type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge".


If you don't expect "remoteFile" to exist on the type "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge" it is most likely a typo.

However, if you expect "remoteFile" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:


- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server

- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what shape they have

- You want to optionally use your field "remoteFile" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL schema. A quick fix is to add a least one entry with that field ("dummy content")


It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "WpNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdge":

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#creating-type-definitions


File: src/templates/types/page.js:135:7


failed extract queries from components - 1.396s

success write out redirect data - 0.113s

success Build manifest and related icons - 0.255s

success onPostBootstrap - 0.274s

info bootstrap finished - 29.400s

success run static queries - 0.026s - 2/2 77.74/s

success run page queries - 0.038s - 8/8 208.53/s

success write out requires - 0.016s


ERROR #11321 PLUGIN


"gatsby-plugin-notifications" threw an error while running the onCreateDevServer lifecycle:


Cannot destructure property 'activationValue' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.


45 | timeout: 15,

46 | },

> 47 | function (_err, _response, { activationValue }) {

| ^

48 | if ([`open app`, `open both`].includes(activationValue)) {

49 | open(`http://localhost:8000`)

50 | }


File: node_modules/gatsby-plugin-notifications/gatsby-node.js:47:36




TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'activationValue' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.


- gatsby-node.js:47

[www]/[gatsby-plugin-notifications]/gatsby-node.js:47:36


- notifysend.js:69 NotifySend.notifyRaw

[www]/[node-notifier]/notifiers/notifysend.js:69:12


- gatsby-node.js:37 Object.exports.onCreateDevServer

[www]/[gatsby-plugin-notifications]/gatsby-node.js:37:14


- api-runner-node.js:229 runAPI

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:229:22


- api-runner-node.js:339 Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:339:17


- api-runner-node.js:338

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:338:14


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:330

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:330:13


- From previous event:


- api-runner-node.js:246 module.exports

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:246:3


- start-server.ts:291 startServer

[www]/[gatsby]/src/utils/start-server.ts:291:9


- start-webpack-server.ts:35 startWebpackServer

[www]/[gatsby]/src/services/start-webpack-server.ts:35:57


- develop-process.ts:140 module.exports

[www]/[gatsby]/src/commands/develop-process.ts:140:3



⠀

info gatsby-source-wordpress Watching for WordPress changes

⠀

You can now view www.mysite.com in the browser.

⠀

http://localhost:8000/

⠀

View GraphiQL, an in-browser IDE, to explore your site's data and schema

⠀

http://localhost:8000/___graphql

⠀

Note that the development build is not optimized.

To create a production build, use gatsby build

⠀

success Building development bundle - 9.886s
```

Wordpress seems to be running fine. I can access & query GraphQL using the WP GraphiQL interface in the Wordpress admin area.

**Wordpress + Plugins**

```
Wordpress 5.4.2
Advanced Custom Fields PRO Version 5.8.12   
WP Gatsby Version 0.4.16
WP GraphiQL Version 1.0.1   
WP GraphQL Version 0.12.0
WP Offload Media Lite Version 2.4.1
WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields Version 0.3.3
```

Note, the `WP GraphQL` version says `0.12.0` when listed in the WordPress Plugins page, but I grabbed the files from the `0.12.1` release [from the documentation](https://github.com/TylerBarnes/using-gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/blob/master/WordPress/plugins/wp-graphql-0.12.1.zip). I suspect this is just an oversight of the project owner not updating the version number in the source code.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "www.mysite.com",
  "private": true,
  "description": "site description",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Me",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "gatsby": "2.24.47",
    "gatsby-image": "2.4.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-chakra-ui": "0.1.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.4.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cache": "1.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-notifications": "0.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "3.2.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.3.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "2.6.27",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "2.4.18",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "2.3.24",
    "gatsby-source-graphql": "2.7.1",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental": "1.3.6",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.5.13",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.10.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.0.27",
    "@types/react": "16.9.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8",
    "@types/react-helmet": "6.0.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.7.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "0.1.11",
    "eslint": "7.5.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.2.2",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.4",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "develop-docker": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.tsx",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit"
  }
}
```

Any ideas why these fields are referenced in the starter kit, yet are not defined return from the GraphQL?

Answer (score 1):

For future Google spelunkers, `menuItemId` appears to now be `databaseId` on items in the `menuItems` collection. Also, items like `featuredImage` now nest their details (ex: `altText`, `title`, etc.) within a nested `node` underneath it.

Unfortunately I can't answer the rest of the errors you are seeing, but I'd suggest you run `gatsby develop` and then visit `http://localhost:8000/__graphql` and browse the nodes of your query to figure out the new mappings.